SDL2 Program Crashes After Generating Random Pixels for a Few Seconds
I am working on a project using SDL2 to generate random pixels in a terminal display.
My program compiles and runs:
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <random>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_Window* window = nullptr;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = nullptr;

    if (SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(2000, 2000, 0, &window, &renderer) != 0) {
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_RenderSetScale(renderer, 20, 20);

    int x{25};
    int y{25};

    std::random_device dev;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint8_t> nd(0, 3);

    while (true) {
        uint8_t dir = nd(dev);
        Uint8 r, g, b;

        switch (dir) {
            case 0:
                x -= 1;
                y -= 1;
                r = 245;
                g = 169;
                b = 184;
                break;
            case 1:
                x += 1;
                y -= 1;
                r = 91;
                g = 206;
                b = 250;
                break;
            case 2:
                x -= 1;
                y += 1;
                r = 255;
                g = 255;
                b = 255;
                break;
            case 3:
                x += 1;
                y += 1;
                r = 0;
                g = 0;
                b = 0;
                break;
        }

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, r, g, b, 255);
        SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, x, y);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

        if (x > 50 || x < 0 || y > 50 || y < 0) {
            x = 25;
            y = 25;
        }

        
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}

...but it crashes after generating random pixels for about 2 seconds.
Any help or leads?
I am using MSYS with a C++20 compiler.

Your check for out of renderer is done after the draw....

Sanity and chatGPT dont go well together.... ChatGPT may have looked at tons of C++ code, but most of that is bad or outdated. So it will not have learned the right things. That said... are you sure your pixels stay withing the boundary of your window? (I have no idea how "low level" SDL gets but it might be starting to access memory out of bounds)

@Jarod42 Ah yes that explains it ;)

Also check return error of functions.

The pixels stay in the boundary due to the if loop.  It returns the renderer back to the centre. No return errors cuz runtime :(

Hello! starlitdreams, while( true ) is bad idea, you have a infinite loop, the break work in the switch, you need a boolean: while( same ) { and same = false;.

Please install a debugger. The one in Visual Studio Community will give you the option to break into the debugger when a crash happens. When you break into the debugger inspect the variables and call stack to attempt to determine what is wrong / unexpected.

Where's your SDL_PumpEvents()/SDL_PollEvent() call?  Never processing any OS/window-system events rarely goes well for your process.

Never processing any OS/window-system events rarely goes well for your process. Failing to process window events would make your window appear to freeze and not update.

Sorta fixed it after using the comments:
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <random>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Window* window = nullptr;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = nullptr;

    if (SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(2000, 2000, 0, &window, &renderer) != 0) {
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_RenderSetScale(renderer, 20, 20);

    int x{25};
    int y{25};

    std::random_device dev;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint8_t> nd(0, 3);

    bool running = true;
    while (running) {
        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                running = false;
            }
        }

        uint8_t dir = nd(dev);
        Uint8 r, g, b;

        switch (dir) {
            case 0:
                x -= 1;
                y -= 1;
                r = 245;
                g = 169;
                b = 184;
                break;
            case 1:
                x += 1;
                y -= 1;
                r = 91;
                g = 206;
                b = 250;
                break;
            case 2:
                x -= 1;
                y += 1;
                r = 255;
                g = 255;
                b = 255;
                break;
            case 3:
                x += 1;
                y += 1;
                r = 0;
                g = 0;
                b = 0;
                break;
        }

        if (x >= 0 && x <= 50 && y >= 0 && y <= 50) {
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, r, g, b, 255);
            SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, x, y);
            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        }

        if (x > 50 || x < 0 || y > 50 || y < 0) {
            x = 25;
            y = 25;
        }
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}

tysm for the help , problem solved :)
